# Python RegEx - Single vs multiple line test

Tags: python, regex

re.finditer() will pick the (.com) is the below text is in multiline string. The same function does not work if the text is in a single string (var ss). Can anyone please help me to understand?

```
s = """  example (.com) 
  w3resource github (.com) 
    stackoverflow (.com) """

# ss = """  example (.com) w3resource github (.com) stackoverflow (.com) """
match = re.finditer(r'\(.+\)',s)
print(match)
for i in match:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot ( . ) will match any character except a newline, so in first case your greedy + stops when it finds the newline, on the later case, the greedy + works till the last parenthesis and hence perform only a single match.So it means your regex should be modified, try replacing it with below, so what I wrote it is this:
Inside a parenthesis , match a literal dot (escaped here) with a word (one or more characters) followed by a closing parenthesis. The output matches as expected

```
import re
s = """  example (.com) 
  w3resource github (.com) 
    stackoverflow (.com) """

ss = """  example (.com) w3resource github (.com) stackoverflow (.com) """
match = re.finditer(r'\(\.\w+\)',ss) ## changes are done here
print(match)
for i in match:
    print(i)
```

Comment: @user1787414 please select answer as ticked so that it can be closed